# How can I check if a Networkprinter is connected?

Tags: windows, powershell

I would like to check the connection of my networkprinter.
I connected my printer with

```
Add-Printer -ConnectionName $Printer
```

and now want to know if the connecting was succesfull. I tried it with

```
gwmi win32_printer -ComputerName $Printername
```

and now want to put it in a if so I can output connected or not connected.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: What do you by check the connection, as in if it responds to a ping? What have you tried? Also, you've tagged Powershell 3 and 2; both of which are pretty old versions. Powershell 2 came with Windows 7; are you really using that still?

Comment: If you want to check if the printer was added, why not use [`Get-Printer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/printmanagement/get-printer?view=win10-ps)?

Comment: @Larnu Like Get-Printer -ComputerName $Printername? If so how can I output connected or unconnected?

Comment: You can check variable `PrinterStatus` , like this `Get-Printer -Name \\printer\safeq| select PrinterStatus`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your must be look like this:

```
Add-Printer -ConnectionName $Printer 
if((Get-Printer -Name $printer).PrinterStatus -eq "Normal"){
Write-host "Connection is successful"
}else{
 do something....
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply this...

```
Clear-Host
Get-Printer | 
ForEach {"The printer named `"$($PSItem.Name)`" connection status is: $($PSItem.PrinterStatus)"}

<#
The printer named "OneNote" connection status is: Normal
...
The printer named "Microsoft XPS Document Writer" connection status is: Normal
The printer named "Microsoft Print to PDF" connection status is: Normal
The printer named "Fax" connection status is: Normal
...
#>
```