# How can I try to connect a networkprinter and output a text saying if the connecting was succesfull or not?(powershell)

Tags: powershell

How can I try to connect a networkprinter and output a text saying if the connecting was succesfull or not? I connected my printer with `Add-Printer` and now want to check and output a text saying if the connection was succesfull or not. If the connection was unsuccesfull it should try again twice.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Why you create duplicate account?? it's not normal [another user account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60535039/how-can-i-check-if-a-networkprinter-is-connected)

Your must be look like this:

```
Add-Printer -ConnectionName $Printer 
if((Get-Printer -Name $printer).PrinterStatus -eq "Normal"){
Write-host "Connection is successful"
}else{
 Write-host "Connection is failed"
 }
```